# ArcGIS Javascript API - IE9 Quirks Mode

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, svg, dojo

I'm having difficulty understanding why ArcGIS Javascript API isn't rendering SVG when running in IE9 quirks mode.

When I visit the ESRI sample site at http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/graphics/graphics_add.html and switch to IE 9 + Quirks mode I notice dojox/gfx/vml.xd.js loads but vector rendering does not work.  Point, Multipoint, Extent all work fine but anything gfx related (polyline, freehand, line) does not work.

Is it possible to use dojo/ArcGIS Javascript API in IE9 + Quirks mode?  The reason I ask is because the  pages I'm embedding the map in must run in this mode.

Comment: Try the HTML Meta Tags here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097868/ie9-svg-onload-accessing-parent-top

Comment: I have confirmed that dojo tests below work in IE9 quirks mode:
http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.0/dojo-release-1.6.0/dojox/gfx/tests/test_gfx.html

Comment: Mapperz...in standards mode it uses SVG and works fine but I am constrained to quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here isn't with the dojo/ArcGIS, it's with SVG in IE in quirks mode. [IE does not have SVG support below version 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926285/svg-browser-support) and by putting IE9 in quirks mode you're telling it to act like an older browser.

Whether it is possible to use dojo/ArcGIS in IE9 quirks mode in general mostly depends on what you're doing [ESRI does not fully support IE below version 9](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/browsers.htm) and a few things don't work in newer IE versions either (also listed at the link).

This StackOverflow question on [how to get SVG to work in older versions of IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427051/how-to-make-svg-work-with-ie) may help you.